# Graph Theory and Dijkstra's Algoirthm

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to use Dijkstra's Algorithm to calculate the best route the score the most objectives in a game within 60 seconds. However, some objectives in the game grant more points when scored. Is there any way I can account for it? Using weighted graphs, I can make certain paths longer than others making it take more time in my situation, however it does not help me with my main issue. If anyone can help me in addressing this situation, or tell me about another pathfinding algorithm that may help me account for this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to use weighted graph for problems like this. The Algorithm stays the same except that the length of paths change .